# How to force ffmpeg download live m3u8 from the first available segment?

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

When I use ffmpeg straight forward like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 'playlist.m3u8' -c copy out.mp4
```

it searches for current segment (or maybe the last one) and drops all previous.

I know that live playlist is a sliding window and contains only the last part of all segments. Even if there are some older segments in a m3u8 file, ffmpeg skips them but I want to download them too. I don't want to start from the very beginning of the stream I just need to prevent that skips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command, it worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -live_start_index -99999 -i https://your_url/source.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc outputtt.mp4
```